# Automatic Upload not working in Webstorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I have the "Upload changed files automatically to the default server" set to "Always", however it is not working. I can only upload files if I right click on the project and select the upload to server context option. If I save a file change there is no automatic upload happening.

This used to work for me before. Any idea what i could be doing wrong?

Comment: Screenshot with your settings are welcome. Quite possible you have missed something. BTW -- " select the upload to server context option" -- what is the name of such context entry EXACTLY?

Comment: i think the problem was that I used a copy of another project, and just adjusted that. I started a fresh new project, and it seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I coped across another **.idea** folder from another project and adjusted that.

I started a fresh new projet and it seems to work fine.

Lesson learned, don't reuse other projects in idea. Always create a fresh new project

Answer (score 0):

If you want reuse a project,first create a new project and configure your ftp Connection,then copy files into this project .